# PHP Array to string conversion error only when using values from POST request

Tags: php, arrays, post, request

I'm developing a Java desktop application that sends a HTTP POST request with certain parameters, and a php script requests those parameters and inserts their values in a MS SQL Server database.

Here's the php script:

```
<?php

$id=$_REQUEST['id']; 
$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
$dob=$_REQUEST['dob'];

$serverName = "local";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"myDB","UID" => "sa","PWD" => "sa");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn )
{
     echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql= "INSERT INTO dbo.patientdata (id,name,gender,dob) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$var= array($id,$name,$gender,$dob);

if (!sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$var))
                 {
            die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                 }
            echo "1 record added"; 

?>
```

During the process an "Array to string conversion error" occurs. The plot twist is: if I  define the variables in the PHP script rather then using $_REQUEST (ex.: $name="Jane" instead of $name=$_REQUEST['name']) the error doesn't occur, so I figure I'm not sending or requesting the parameters correctly. Here's an example of the POST parameters being sent.

```
id=9001&name="John"&gender=1&dob="1999-01-01"
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST);` and you will know why, On  a related side note why do your post parameters have quotes in them?

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST) 

array(4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "9001" ["name"]=> string(4) "John" ["gender"]=>  string(1) "1" ["dob"]=> string(10) "1999-01-01" }

Comment: i quoted parameters that are strings

Comment: I don't think binding or putting a variable in a statement needs to put quotes. Those class and functions will do it for you. I don't know why you said this is a $_POST as you post `id=9001&name="John"&gender=1&dob="1999-01-01"` in the question, but it seems to be working if you remove those quotes `id=9001&name=John&gender=1&dob=1999-01-01`.